# Mapping an int to a struct of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am trying to learn how `std::map` works, I have the following problem:

```
int id; // stores some id

struct stuff {
  std::vector<int> As;
  std::vector<int> Bs;
} stuff;

std::map<int, stuff> smap;

void foo () {
  int count = 2;
  int foo_id = 43;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; count++) {
        stuff.As.push_back(count);
        stuff.Bs.push_back(count);
  }
  smap.insert(foo_id, stuff);
}
```

Currently I get:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
  std::map<int, stuff> smap;

error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘smap’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   smap.insert(int, stuff);
```

I want to be able to map the `id` to the `struct` which is made of two vectors being populated in a for loop. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to map this?

Comment: Try renaming one of the 2 `stuff`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct stuff` defines `stuff` as a `struct`, but then `} stuff;` on the end redefines `stuff` as a variable of type `stuff`.

```
struct stuff { // stuff is a struct
  std::vector<int> As;
  std::vector<int> Bs;
} stuff; // stuff is now a variable of type stuff.
```

As a result, there is no type named `stuff` for `std::map<int, stuff>` to use.

You can resolve the problem by renaming the struct type:

```
struct stuff_t {
  std::vector<int> As;
  std::vector<int> Bs;
} stuff;

std::map<int, stuff_t> smap;
```

Comment: That worked! Also, is insert the best way to add stuff to the map? How should I go about doing that?

Comment: @Blizzard In that case you should post a new question.

Comment: @Blizzard hard to answer that one. Best relative to what? `smap[foo_id] = stuff;` is pretty easy to read. `smap.insert(foo_id, stuff);` might be a bit faster. `emplace` may allow you to dodge some redundant assignments and constructions by constructing everything in place.